# Float version of ```numpy.random.randint()```

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a function in python which returns random float values in particular range like `np.random.randint()`

I am specifically asking because `randint` has in-built arguments where we can specify how many random numbers we want in that particular range.

For example what I want is `some_function(start,stop,n)` Here n is no of random values I want.

What `np.random.randint(1,6,4)` does is return something like this:

`array([2,2,3,4])`

I want the same kind of function which generates random float values

Comment: `numpy.random.rand`

Comment: @PeterMeisrimel No what this does is give a n X n matrix of random numbers.What ```np.random.randint``` does is return a 1 X 1 matrix of n random floats

Comment: Sorry could you add an example of what you want to get ?

Comment: `(stop-start)*numpy.random.rand(n) + start`